# remove blank lines & extra space within lists - python

Tags: python, python-2.7

My data in list look like this:

```
data = [u'Gluten free menu includes gluten free rolls for sandwiches and gluten free brownies! There are also many dishes that can be adjusted to be gluten free.',
 u"They use the same slicing machine for diary and meats.  Manager was knowledgable about food prep, servers were not.\r\r\r\n\r\r\r\nWe've been very select about which foods to order, but haven't had any issues.",
 u'The restaurant has a whole gluten free section of the menu and says that they will accommodate any allergies.  I myself do not have allergies but grandchildren have dairy, egg nut and niece has gluten.',
 u'Got sick from crosscontam Bfast. I suggest ordering the Mexican dishes if cross contam is an issue. My fav place in Sedona tho food is great!']
```

The output I am looking for is:

```
Gluten free menu includes gluten free rolls for sandwiches and gluten free brownies! There are also many dishes that can be adjusted to be gluten free.
They use the same slicing machine for diary and meats.  Manager was knowledgable about food prep, servers were not. We've been very select about which foods to order, but haven't had any issues.
The restaurant has a whole gluten free section of the menu and says that they will accommodate any allergies.  I myself do not have allergies but grandchildren have dairy, egg nut and niece has gluten.
Got sick from crosscontam Bfast. I suggest ordering the Mexican dishes if cross contam is an issue. My fav place in Sedona tho food is great!
```

I tried different codes, including the following example:

```
for sentence in data:
    print sentence.strip()
```

Nothing seems to work. Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have an single-line string that isn't terminated in line 3, resulting in a syntax error. Is this intended?

Comment: I have posted the real data.

Comment: @kevin Do you want to keep the `two spaces` between words as two spaces? And only changes any amount of newlines to a single space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the multi-line string is correctly created using three quotes.

`str.strip()` only strips the trailing and leading whitespaces, not the ones in between.

The easiest way to do this would be to first `split()` the complete string on any whitespace, and then `str.join()` then back using one space.

Example -

```
for sentence in data:
    print ' '.join(sentence.split())
```

---

Demo with the edited real data -

```
>>> data = [u'Gluten free menu includes gluten free rolls for sandwiches and gluten free brownies! There are also many dishes that can be adjusted to be gluten free.',
...  u"They use the same slicing machine for diary and meats.  Manager was knowledgable about food prep, servers were not.\r\r\r\n\r\r\r\nWe've been very select about which foods to order, but haven't had any issues.",
...  u'The restaurant has a whole gluten free section of the menu and says that they will accommodate any allergies.  I myself do not have allergies but grandchildren have dairy, egg nut and niece has gluten.',
...  u'Got sick from crosscontam Bfast. I suggest ordering the Mexican dishes if cross contam is an issue. My fav place in Sedona tho food is great!']
>>>
>>> for sentence in data:
...     print(' '.join(sentence.split()))
...
Gluten free menu includes gluten free rolls for sandwiches and gluten free brownies! There are also many dishes that can be adjusted to be gluten free.
They use the same slicing machine for diary and meats. Manager was knowledgable about food prep, servers were not. We've been very select about which foods to order, but haven't had any issues.
The restaurant has a whole gluten free section of the menu and says that they will accommodate any allergies. I myself do not have allergies but grandchildren have dairy, egg nut and niece has gluten.
Got sick from crosscontam Bfast. I suggest ordering the Mexican dishes if cross contam is an issue. My fav place in Sedona tho food is great!
```

Comment: @kevin Do you want to keep the two spaces between words as two spaces? And only changes any amount of newlines to a single space?

Comment: It would be better to have a single space between words. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Given (your example):

```
>>> data = [u'Gluten free menu includes gluten free rolls for sandwiches and gluten free brownies! There are also many dishes that can be adjusted to be gluten free.',
...  u"They use the same slicing machine for diary and meats.  Manager was knowledgable about food prep, servers were not.\r\r\r\n\r\r\r\nWe've been very select about which foods to order, but haven't had any issues.",
...  u'The restaurant has a whole gluten free section of the menu and says that they will accommodate any allergies.  I myself do not have allergies but grandchildren have dairy, egg nut and niece has gluten.',
...  u'Got sick from crosscontam Bfast. I suggest ordering the Mexican dishes if cross contam is an issue. My fav place in Sedona tho food is great!']
```

You can do:

```
>>> import re
>>> data=[re.sub(r'[\n\r]', '', e) for e in data]
>>> print '\n'.join(data)
```

Prints:

```
Gluten free menu includes gluten free rolls for sandwiches and gluten free brownies! There are also many dishes that can be adjusted to be gluten free.
They use the same slicing machine for diary and meats.  Manager was knowledgable about food prep, servers were not.We've been very select about which foods to order, but haven't had any issues.
The restaurant has a whole gluten free section of the menu and says that they will accommodate any allergies.  I myself do not have allergies but grandchildren have dairy, egg nut and niece has gluten.
Got sick from crosscontam Bfast. I suggest ordering the Mexican dishes if cross contam is an issue. My fav place in Sedona tho food is great!
```